# Visual Representation of API's in Pycharm or 3rd party program

Tags: api, pycharm, graphical-interaction

I have scoured the web and have not been able to find a answer to this.

Is anyone aware of a way to display API's in a graphical map - to display all of the fields available via the API - ideally in a graphical representation of whats exposed (like a mind map) or hierarchical representation.

I'm using Pycharm, and working with about 50 different API's for this project.  (facebook, twitter, etc).

Any insights appreciated greatly.

David

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to do this in pycharm (i.e. it's a feature) or some programmatic way to accomplish this?